# Laravel: request->user() in boot() method on model (GlobalScope)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have some behaviour I cannot explain. I am in the middle of a rather big refactor and I bumped into an issue that has been in the code for a long time, but it seemed to work before the refactor.

On some models `static::addGlobalScope` is used to extend some queries where needed. In this callback method the user that performs the request is fetched with `request()->user()`. This works inside the callback without issues, but when moved outside the callback this returns `null`.

Working example:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope('auth', function (Builder $builder) {
        $user = request()->user();

        if ($user) {
            if ($user->role == 'consultant') {
                $builder->where('user_id', $user->id);
            } elseif ($user->role == 'approver') {
                $builder->whereHas('contract', function ($query) use ($user) {
                    return $query->whereHas('approvers', function ($query) use ($user) {
                        return $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Example where `$user` is null.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    $user = request()->user(); // Moved $user outside of the callback

    static::addGlobalScope('auth', function (Builder $builder) use ($user) {
        if ($user) {
            if ($user->role == 'consultant') {
                $builder->where('user_id', $user->id);
            } elseif ($user->role == 'approver') {
                $builder->whereHas('contract', function ($query) use ($user) {
                    return $query->whereHas('approvers', function ($query) use ($user) {
                        return $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The second example has been taken from a model before the refactor.
This method is being used on multiple models, this never gave any issues. Does anyone have an idea why `$user` is null when `request()->user()` is called outside of the callback in the `boot` method? And most important, why it never gave issues before?

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with the fact that in order to get the user when you use request()->user() it has to register all the global scopes and then execute the query. It actually checks if session exists and then queries to get that user to return user object. Maybe you need to use local scope or maybe Auth::check() will do the job.

Comment: When I place `request->user()`  outside the callback, this returns `null`. When placed inside the callback, it works as expected. I do however seem to remember that I once read that the `request()` method does not work inside `boot()` methods in laravel, but why and how I do not know.

Comment: Did you changed the laravel version? Maybe now boot hooks of the models run before session middleware. Can you try this? Auth::user();

Comment: Laravel has been updated indeed, `Auth::user()` does not work outside the callback. When placed inside the callback `Auth::user()` works as intended.

Comment: Can you add a dd($user) before static::addGlobalScope and post what you get?

Comment: As stated in the question, this returns `null`. This issue has something to do with the session midleware. I'm getting close with finding the issue. Will provide an answer when I am certain.

Comment: Yeap i told you that in a previous comment but i think i found the reason this happens. This may have to do with the fact that in order to get the user when you use request()->user() it has to register all the global scopes and then execute the query. It actually checks if session exists and then queries to get that user. Maybe you need to use local scope or maybe Auth::check() will do the job.